# Change value according to match in another tab in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have two df such as

**df1**

```
COL1 COL2
A 1
A 2
B 3
B 4
C 5
D 6
E 7
F 8
```

**df2**

```
Old New 
A  A.1
C  C.1
E  E.1
```

and I would like to replace `COL1`values matching in `df2.Ol`d by the `df2.New` value.

And get :
**df1**

```
COL1 COL2
A.1 1
A.1 2
B 3
B 4
C.1 5
D 6
E.1 7
F 8
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''COL1 COL2
A 1
A 2
B 3
B 4
C 5
D 6
E 7
F 8 '''),sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''Old New 
A  A.1
C  C.1
E  E.1 '''),sep='\s+')

df1['COL1'] = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'Old':'COL1'}),on='COL1',how='left')['New'].fillna(df1['COL1'])
```

Output:

```
    COL1    COL2
0   A.1 1
1   A.1 2
2   B   3
3   B   4
4   C.1 5
5   D   6
6   E.1 7
7   F   8
```

Comment: @Grendel This answer uses `merge` which will be slower as compared to my answer. You can check time comparisons in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
In [516]: x = df2.set_index('Old').to_dict()['New']

In [519]: df1['COL1'] = df1['COL1'].map(x).fillna(df1['COL1'])

In [521]: df1
Out[521]: 
  COL1  COL2
0  A.1     1
1  A.1     2
2    B     3
3    B     4
4  C.1     5
5    D     6
6  E.1     7
7    F     8
```

**Time comparisons**:

@adir bargirl's answer:

```
In [540]: def f1():
     ...:     df1['COL1'] = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'Old':'COL1'}),on='COL1',how='left')['New'].fillna(df1['COL1'])
     ...: 

In [542]: %timeit f1()
2.09 ms ± 74.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

My answer:

```
In [541]: def f2():
     ...:     x = df2.set_index('Old').to_dict()['New']
     ...:     df1['COL1'] = df1['COL1'].map(x).fillna(df1['COL1'])
     ...: 

In [543]: %timeit f2()
1.06 ms ± 14.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```